# User input is not saving in my firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a sign-up and sign-in page for a web app, with the data to be stored in firebase. I am just following instructions said here, but it doesn't work. I am using the 9.23 version of firebasejs while the tutorial uses the 9.15 version.

https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-connect-an-html-registration-form-to-firebase

The other functions of my code work: such as an alert when the user inputs an email that doesnt match the pattern for emails, or when the user inputs a password less than 7 according to what firebase accepts. So I think the problem doesnt come from reading user input, it comes from saving the input to firebase.

Edit for additional information about the problem:

Instead of seeing an alert according to the function I made and seeing the data saved to firebase after clicking the submit button, what happens is that the page just refreshes and no notification or alert that it was saved AND no error alert would show up—as in it just refreshes and all the user input would be gone.

So here is the function that I followed from the tutorial that is supposed to set the data to the firebase:

```js
function register(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    const lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
    const uname = document.getElementById('uname').value;
    const email = document.getElementById('inputEmail').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('inputPassword').value;
    const repPassword = document.getElementById('repPassword').value;

    //validate input fields
    if (validate_email(email) == false){
        alert('Please enter a valid email.')
    } 
    if (validate_passwordLen(password) == false) {
        alert('Please enter a password with more than 6 characters.')
    }
    if (validate_passwordRep(password,repPassword) == false){
        alert('Passwords do not match. Account creation failed.')
    }
    if (validate_field(fname) == false || validate_field(lname) == false || validate_field(uname) == false) {
        alert('Please enter a valid information.')
    }

    sendMessage(fname,lname,uname,email);
  }
```

Here is the function that I made that will be done once the user clicks submit.

And this function is made to insert the user input to the firebase. However the error says:

```js
function sendMessage (fname, lname, uname, email) {
      set(ref(database, 'users/' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000)), {
        fname: fname,
        lname: lname,
        uname: uname,
        email: email,
        last_login: Date.now()
      }).then(() => {
        alert('Account created successfully')
        document.getElementById('registerform').reset()
      }).catch((error) => {
        alert(error)
      })
    }
```

Edit:

I also imported the following, and made sure it was called before linking my js file:

Uncaught reference error: set is not defined

```html
<script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-app.js";
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-analytics.js";
  import { getDatabase, set, ref } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-database.js";
  import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-auth.js"
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  const firebaseConfig = {
  //...
  };
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
  // Initialize variables
  const auth = getAuth();
  const database = getDatabase(app);
  
</script>
```

Update:

I just saw that the error was:
Uncaught reference error: fireauth is not defined

Uncaught reference error: set is not defined

But as you can see, I imported set from https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-database.js

What must have been wrong? Thank you so much in advance for enlightening me! I must admit I am new to this but unfortunately I need to get this done as soon as possible

Comment: Hi Jelly, do you get any errors? What happens when you try to save the input to firebase? And have you checked out the official docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start#web-modular-api

Comment: When i click the submit button, it just refreshes the page and no errors would alert. But for example, when i purposely entered a password less than 7 characters, there will be an alert based on the function that I defined.

Comment: Have you tried it with preventDefault(); https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault and with console logging the input?

Comment: I updated the description of the problem and added the function that will be called once the user clicks submit. And there I added the e.preventDefault(); but what happened was the other alerts, such as the mismatched password alert, did not work. Regarding the console logging the input, I never tried it... May you enlighten me about it?

Comment: How you are including your JS code? Kindly add that code too.

Answer (score 1):

Add `if and else if` ladder so that if one condition fails, it will not continue. So that `firebase` modules gets initialized before your script gets executed.

```js
function register(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    const fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    const lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
    const uname = document.getElementById('uname').value;
    const email = document.getElementById('inputEmail').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('inputPassword').value;
    const repPassword = document.getElementById('repPassword').value;

    //validate input fields
    if (validate_email(email) == false){
        alert('Please enter a valid email.')
    } 
    else if (validate_passwordLen(password) == false) {
        alert('Please enter a password with more than 6 characters.')
    }
    else if (validate_passwordRep(password,repPassword) == false){
        alert('Passwords do not match. Account creation failed.')
    }
    else if (validate_field(fname) == false || validate_field(lname) == false || validate_field(uname) == false) {
        alert('Please enter a valid information.')
    }
    else {
        sendMessage(fname,lname,uname,email);
    }
  }
```

In your HTML file, while including the script, maintain the order.

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <form onsubmit="register(event);">
       ....
      </form>
      <script type="module">
         import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-app.js";
         import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-analytics.js";
         import { getDatabase, set, ref } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-database.js";
         import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-auth.js"
         
         const firebaseConfig = {
         //...
         };
         const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
         const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
          
         const auth = getAuth();
         const database = getDatabase(app);
         
      </script>
      <script src="path/to/js/file.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it gives me the errors: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault') and Uncaught ReferenceError: set is not defined Regarding the js. file, yes I made sure that I maintained the order of import.

Comment: Updated the answer. Failed to add param to the function.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you for the answer, I realized that I also forgot to put the parameter but unfortunately it still didn't worked :<